# What is the Literal Translation of "vestigio suo" in Suetonius' "Divus Augustus 28.2"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

In Suetonius' "Div. Aug. 28.2":

> "...et moriens ut feram mecum spem mansura in vestigio suo fundamenta rei publicae quae iecero." =

> "...and in dying I will carry the hope with me, that the foundations which I have laid for its future government will stand firm and stable." (Perseus: Alexander Thomson, 1889)

In John-Buchan's book, "Augustus", p.129:

> "...and bear with me the hope when I die that the foundations that I have laid will remain unshaken."

The neuter noun, "vestigium", has its well-known definitions: "footprint"; "track"; "sole-of-foot"; "imprint"; "vestige"; in the ablative, "e vestigio" = "immediately" (Oxford; L&S). The translations of "vestigio suo" = "firm"; "stable"; "unshaken", above, do not appear to fit with any of these established ones; apart from, "in its foot", which sounds fatuous.

What's going on, here?

Comment: mansura in vestigio suo → are to remain on their track. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I agree with Rafael. Caesar uses the phrase eodem remanere vestigio, meaning ‘to remain in the same place’. Here the phrase, referring to the foundations, expresses Augustus’s hope that ‘the foundations he has laid will remain in their place’, i.e. unalterable.

Comment: @Rafael: Being "on track" may provide guidance for future direction but is it synonymous with "firm"/ "stable"?

Comment: @Jonathan Hadfield: If it is simply a matter of remaining in the same place why not just say, "in suo loco"? I am going to annotate my copy of the OLD with your interpretation. Interesting that dictionaries do not recognise this.

Comment: I guess it's just free (as opposed to literal) translation

Comment: in suo vestigio is different from in suo loco since it means ‘in the place where they stood’ cf. in suo vestigio mori ‘to die in the spot on which they stand’. Livy 28, 22:- neminem cedere atque obstinatos mori in vestigio quemque suo vidit’ ‘when they [vetus miles= collective subject] no-one giving way and resolutely dying in their tracks’ i.e. exactly where they stood. vestigio as opposed to loco means exactly where they stood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Vestigium* can just mean "a spot, a specific place," even in time. For instance, [eodem vestigio](https://latin.packhum.org/search?q=eodem%20%7E%20vestigio) means "in that same spot" or even "at that same moment."

OLD gives *in vestigio* as "in (the same) position; where one stands."

[Lewis & Short](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/vestigium) renders *eodem remanare vestigio* in Caesar as *to stay in the same spot or place*. That's pretty similar to *mansura in vestigio suo*: will remain in their place (where they currently stand).

Comment: Could it have been written as, "in statu quo"?

Comment: See the OED:- As the Oxford English Dictionary explains, ‘status quo (Latin for the state in which) showed up in the fifth century in the writings of Augustine of Hippo (St. Augustine), and was “probably extrapolated from in statu quo” (in the state in which).

Comment: @tony “in statu suo” with a similar meaning: in their current place/condition